# how to upload a video on facebook

Tags: video, facebook

On the facebook help page I found:

`Click Add Photos/Video at the top of your homepage...`

But there is only Photo link on my page, without video heading or option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com). Go to your news feed. This is it right here:

[image]

Comment: @SunSky No problem mate :)